# UISwipeGestureRecognizer in UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I want to put two swipe gesture recognizers in a UIImageView but gestures aren't recognized. Only recognizes the tap gesture.

This is my code:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {

  //Acciones
     img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[urls
                                                                                       objectAtIndex:index]]]];

    UIImage *img2;

    if (img.size.height > img.size.width) {
         img2 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: img.CGImage scale:1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationUp];
     }else{
         img2 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: img.CGImage scale:1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationRight];
    }

     imageSelected.image = img2;
     [imageSelected setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
     imageSelected.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
     imageSelected.backgroundColor= [UIColor whiteColor];

     UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap =  [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(exitAction:)];
     [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
     [imageSelected addGestureRecognizer:singleTap]; 

     UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwipe:)];
     swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
     [imageSelected addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

     UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(leftSwipe:)];
     swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
     [imageSelected addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];

 }
```

Swipe function:

```
 -(IBAction)leftSwipe:(id)sender{ NSLog(@"Left Swipe");    }
```

Thank you for advance.

Comment: What are the `>` characters for?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with your code. How do you know the swipe gesture doesn't work? Is it possible that you are just not performing the gesture correctly?

Comment: This characters aren't at code.

Comment: The NSLog not appear at console. I'm doing correctly the gesture

Comment: sometimes appear this: Gesture: Failed to receive system gesture state notification before next touch

Comment: What is the superview of imageSelected ?
Have you other swipe gesture in your view hierarchy (a drawer menu for exemple) ?

Comment: The superview is ImageViewController. In this view I haven't gesture recognizers, only in imageSelected

Comment: Mmm I have a left menu slider. It can causes this?

Comment: Set a delegate for your gestures and return `YES` from `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`.

Comment: I disagree with that proposed solution. It's not a question of recognizing them simultaneously (that's used when you want to simultaneously pinch and pan, for example), but rather specifying a precedence in the gestures via `requireGestureRecognizerToFail`.

Comment: Two unrelated observations, also. First, avoid using `dataWithContentsOfURL`. This is synchronous, and if you have a slow network connection, the watchdog process could kill your app. You should request data asynchronously with `NSURLConnection` method `sendAsynchronousRequest` or `NSURLSession` method `dataTaskWithURL`. Second, it looks like your right swipe gesture is using the `leftSwipe:` selector.

Comment: Thank you Rob. I edit my post and put the answer below. My english is very bad and I'm trying to use this platform the best I can, sorry. I know my right swipe use the `leftSwipe:` action. Thank you for the others advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The solution for me was:**

> Set a delegate for your gestures and return YES from
>   gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer: